# Adding id for datepicker for mobile

Tags: javascript, datepicker

Can some please advise how I adjust this code to allow me to use a date picker on desktop and mobile version of my site.

I am using the query datepicker here http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/ but as my desktop and mobile sites are on the same page, i can't sue the id 'datepicker' twice so how can I adjust this code to allow me to also use m_datepicker then I can apply this to the mobile field?

JS

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.paycoservices.co.uk/styles/datepicker.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
<script>
$(function() {
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();  
});
</script>
```

Comment: consider `.class` selector usage

Comment: use another id and call the `.datepicker()` again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or, you can use the HTML5 datepicker, save you some pain:

`<input type="date" name="bday">`

http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/using-html5-input-types-to-enhance-the-mobile-browsing-experience

Answer (score 1):

Just apply it to two id's?:

```
$(function() {
  $("#datepicker, #mobile-datepicker").datepicker();  
});
```

Comment: wasn't sure how to format it ie. #datepicker; #m_datepicker etc. so thanks